How to import package of com.sun.tools.javac.processing with maven for JDK21?
I want to use the annotation processing tool in JDK21. But it shows missing com.sun.tools.javac.processing.
I tried to add the following parameter to Maven:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>21</source>
        <target>21</target>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

But it still doesn't seem to be working.
The complete pom file is as follows
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>async-log</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>async-log-client</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>async-log-client</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.auto.service</groupId>
            <artifactId>auto-service</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>21</source>
                    <target>21</target>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

I found the solution here
Missing artifact com.sun:tools:jar
The modified pom is as follows:
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>21</source>
                    <target>21</target>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

But it seems that you need to import the relevant api's one by one. I would like to know if there is a way to batch import all the packages

This question is similar to: How to pass "-J" options to javac through Maven?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
